# codeception does not see dump.sql

Tags: php, mysql, yii, codeception

I'm using Yii2 with Codeception. The problem is that Codeception seems to not see the database dump. For simplicity, I consider only LoginCept acceptance tests:

```
use tests\_pages\LoginPage;

$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('ensure that login works');
$loginPage = LoginPage::openBy($I);

$I->see('Login', 'h1');

$I->amGoingTo('try to login with empty credentials');
$loginPage->login('', '');
$I->expectTo('see validations errors');
$I->see('Username cannot be blank.');
$I->see('Password cannot be blank.');
...
```

So, when I run

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run tests/acceptance/LoginCept.php
```

everything runs without errors:

```
Acceptance Tests (1) ----------------------------------------
Trying to ensure that login works (LoginCept.php)       Ok
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

But as soon as I add the following line

```
echo $I->grabFromDatabase('user', 'name', ['id' => 1]);
```

the test starts to fail:

```
Acceptance Tests (1) ----------------------------------------
Trying to ensure that login works (LoginCept.php)       Error
-------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 2.11 seconds, Memory: 9.75Mb
There was 1 error:
---------
1) Failed to ensure that login works in LoginCept.php
#1  F:\site\tests\acceptance\LoginCept.php:8  <-- 8 is the number of added line
#2  F:\site\tests\acceptance\LoginCept.php:8
FAILURES!
```

Below I put the detailed info from config files.

codeception.yml file has the following content:

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_log
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_helpers
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    suite_class: \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
    memory_limit: 1024M
    log: true
    colors: true
modules:
    enabled: [Db]
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site_test' 
            user: 'daemon'
            password: 'HsqyJSAbZC3q3KJa'
            dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
```

The print out of \Yii::$app->db gives:

```
yii\db\Connection Object
            (
                [dsn] => mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site_test
                [username] => daemon
                [password] => HsqyJSAbZC3q3KJa
                [attributes] =>
                [pdo] =>
                [enableSchemaCache] =>
                [schemaCacheDuration] => 3600
                ...
           )
```

With the credentials above, I can log in  manually to my database (in phpmyadmin).

The database dump is located in `F:\site\tests\_data\dump.sql`. I've created it from my working database called **site** and made some modification inside it:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `site_test`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
USE `site_test`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` smallint(5),
  `name` varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1,'admin');
```

Codeception **build** command everytime I run it, gives:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/codecept build
Building Guy classes for suites: acceptance, functional, unit
WebGuy includes modules: WebHelper, PhpBrowser
WebGuy.php generated successfully. 48 methods added
TestGuy includes modules: Filesystem, TestHelper, Yii2
TestGuy.php generated successfully. 53 methods added
CodeGuy includes modules: CodeHelper
CodeGuy.php generated successfully. 1 methods added
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that Db module is enabled for your suit configuration.

Then you need to run `codecept build` before using methods of Db module.

Generally you should run it every time you enable or disable modules in test suit configuration.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioned that, but I do it everytime. I'll now mention this in the question.

Comment: Please, run ``./vendor/bin/codecept run tests/acceptance/LoginCept.php --debug`` to see more detailed output

Comment: And please make sure that you enabled Db module in your test suite config (in your case it is acceptance.suit.yml) and then rebuild WebGuy

Comment: Thanks! After copying the Db-config block from codeception.yml to acceptance.suit.yml it started to work!
I thought that settings from codeception.yml would be augmented by others, but it turned out that not all of them are taken into consideration.

Comment: It is not necessary to copy all Db config from global codeception.yml, you just need to enable Db module for acceptance suit adding ``enabled: [Selenium2, Db]`` into ``modules`` section.